# Error while syncing with Zumero Database server

Tags: iphone, database, synchronization, zumero

What is the solutions for below error while syncing with Zumero database server to your local device / machine?

```
 Error 306 (sglib): Local dbfile is not a clone of the server dbfile specified.
../../src/core/client/zum_sync.c:7604
../../src/core/client/zum_sync.c:8877
../../src/core/client/zum_sync.c:9160
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're changing the Zumero DB file frequently then please remove the previous version of local DB file and try to sync again and it'll work..

Basically, DB file is related with local database which is synced. So if you're getting this error then please remove the local version of Database which was created with another DB file.

Hope this works!

Comment: You can always sync multiple DBFiles to separate SQLite databases, just use different filenames for each (e.g. based on the DBFile name).

Comment: Thanks @PaulRoub but I've used different file name on the same zumero server but that didn't work.

Comment: We may be misunderstanding each other, then. My first point - if you're synching to the *same* DBFile (and haven't deleted and recreated it), you should never have to delete the local database. If that seems necessary, please email more details to support@zumero.com so we can help figure that out. Second, are you saying that synching DBFile "a" to "a.db" while synching DBFile "b" to "b.db" doesn't work? Again, if so, I'd be interested to see the code -- something else is up.

Comment: @PaulRoub what I've done is, used same Database name a.db in app and zumero server is same. But on Zumero server, I've different database as well as different DB filename but that didn't work and I had to remove the old a.db file which was created before.